# DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql, can't concat tuple to bytes

Tags: python, mysql

I am running the below code:

```
db = pymysql.connect(host=host, database=db_name, user=user, password=password)
batchsize = 100
for offset in range(0,1000,batchsize):
     df = pd.read_sql(('SELECT * FROM anime LIMIT %s OFFSET %s', (batchsize,offset)), con=db)
     print("rows and columns: ",df.shape)
```

But it is throwing the following error in line 4:

> can't concat tuple to bytes

Any suggestion is welcome.

Comment: Show the full traceback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have wrongly formatted sql string with tuple.

**Change**:

```
df = pd.read_sql(('SELECT * FROM anime LIMIT %s OFFSET %s', (batchsize,offset)), con=db)
```

**To**:

```
df = pd.read_sql(('SELECT * FROM anime LIMIT %s OFFSET %s' % (batchsize,offset)), con=db)
```

When you are binding values using tuple you must use `%` in between formatted string and tuples.

> ```
> >>> k = "uid"
> >>> v = "sa"
> >>> "%s=%s", (k, v)  
> ('%s=%s', ('uid', 'sa'))  
> >>>   
> >>> "%s=%s" % (k, v)
> 'uid=sa'
> ```
>
> The whole expression evaluates to a string.
>   The first `%s` is replaced by the value of `k`;
>   the second `%s` is replaced by the value of `v`.
>   All other characters in the string (in this case, the equal sign) stay as they are.
>   Note that `(k, v)` is a tuple.

**Read**:

- [***Python Library Reference: String Formatting Operations***](https://docs.python.org/2.5/lib/typesseq-strings.html)
- [***Dive Into Python: Formatting Strings***](http://www.diveintopython.net/native_data_types/formatting_strings.html)

Comment: Thank a lot Ravinder.. :-)